# How to filter contacts using Google Contacts API

Tags: google-api, contacts

I can get my complete contacts list via [Google Contacts API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_contacts_using_query_parameters). 
Here is the code :

```
$accessToken = $this->getAccessToken($sso, $authCode);
if (!$accessToken) {
  return null;
}

$contacts = array();
$max_results = 100;
$get = array('max-results' => $max_results, 'oauth_token' => $accessToken, 'alt' => 'json');
$c = curlOutGet('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full', array('get'=>$get,'timeout'=>10),__FILE__.':'.__LINE__.':'.__FUNCTION__);
if ($c['c'] == 200) {
  $jsonContacts = json_decode($c['r']);
  foreach ($jsonContacts->feed->entry as $contact) {
    $email = $contact->{'gd$email'}[0]->{'address'};
    $email = testEmail($email) ? $email : null;
    $contacts[] = array('email' => $email,
            'title' => $contact->{'title'}->{'$t'},
    );
  }
}
```

But I would like to filter given contacts. How I can get only contacts in "My Contacts" list (displayed in Contacts interface on Gmail)?
I would like to filter out contacts in "Other Contacts" list.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: People on StackOverflow will be more willing to help with code & issues, rather then creating code from scratch. I would suggest giving it a try, then posting code and where you get held up